# Mandrill Webhook error

Tags: php, mandrill

mandrill show me following error

```
  Error: POST to https://www.myleadssite.com/MandrillHooknew.php failed with 
  500:    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN"> <html><head> <title>500 Internal Server Error</title> </head><body>
   <h1>Internal Server Error</h1> <p>The server encountered an int
```

and i check using manual response then my code is working fine

and when i setup another webhook with same return url its working fine

my response in in json format.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: If I had an answer, I would give it to you. _In addition to the comments and edits_.

Comment: same happens to me, I really hope somebody figures out a solution.